# Python strptime : time data '"2016-02-02"' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am getting the following error while reading from a csv file using python, when i run the below code :

```
rel_date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[29], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

row[29] is the string which holds the date .

This is my error i get in my log file :

```
ERROR:root: time data '"2016-02-02"' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

I don't know where i am going wrong.
Please help , Thank You

Answer (score 2):

If your `row[29]` variable always contains the string as you specify (with the `"`) then you could change the matching expression as in:

```
rel_date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[29], '"%Y-%m-%d"')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess your string contains the " characters.

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your problem

```
rel_date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[29][1:-1], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: One thing to note here. row[29][1:-1] works faster than row[29].strip('"')

You can try it. 
Suppose
z = '"2016-02-12"'
%timeit z.strip('"')
10000000 loops, best of 3: 169 ns per loop

%timeit z[1:-1]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 64.4 ns per loop

Answer (score 1):

you can use `str.strip` to remove `"`

```
rel_date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[29].strip('"'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```